# Strange behaviour with rand()

Tags: c, random

Why condition rand() % 3 is true approximatelу EVERY 3 time ?  rand is REALY random isn't it ?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: It should be true about 2/3rds of the time.

Comment: `rand()` is not random, it's [pseudo random](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), not the same thing.

Comment: @Darin, pseudo randomness has nothing to do with this sort of test. The resulting numbers are meant to be uniformly distributed, hence if done right the test will result in 66% success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You realize, of course, that even a fair coin can give you ten heads in a row.  There's a probability that can be assigned to that combination.

A fair coin will give half heads and half tails over *many* trials, but it's not guaranteed to be 50/50 over a shorter run.

Your own experience of the physical world tells you that your conclusion is incorrect.   Same is true for rand().

Comment: However, many implementations of `rand()` do show poor randomness, especially if you look at the lower bits.  If the RNG gets caught in a cycle, it be a problem  even if the distribution ends up OK.  If you had a coin toss that went HTHTHTHTHTHTHTHTHT... for a very long stretch, you would suspect something was wrong even though the distribution was exactly as expected.  If the RNG gets caught in a cycle, it can also cause the distribution to skew (forever).

Comment: The DieHard tests ought to be enough to demonstrate whether or not the random number generator is adequate.  Don't know if this implementation has been subjected to it.

Answer (score 1):

As the Linux [manpage for `rand()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) says:

> However, on older rand() implementations, and on current implementations on different systems, the lower-order bits are much less random than the higher-order bits. Do not use this function in applications intended to be portable when good randomness is needed.

So you might want to either use a different random number generator, or pull higher order bits (which may exhibit more randomness).

A typical implementation of `rand()` is a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which is nothing more than a multiply and add of some numbers with special properties (relative primeness).  For example, a couple implementations:

- MSVC 2010 `rand()`:

  ```
   return( ((ptd->_holdrand = ptd->_holdrand * 214013L
              + 2531011L) >> 16) & 0x7fff );
  ```
- `rand()` from IAR workbench:

  ```
   (x) * 1664525L + 1013904223L
  ```

You'll note that MSVC 2010's `rand()` shifts the result to the right, I assume to help with the problem described in the Linux manpage about non-randomness in the lower order bits.

However, if you want to improve the randomness of your results, you might want to look into using a routine based on something like the [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) for which implementations are readily available on the Internet.

Comment: I'm not well versed in statistical analysis or the analysis of the linear congruential algorithm, but if the lower bits are not very random it could well account for a 33% bias.  Note that the quote didn't discuss in detail the behavior of the lower order bits - just that they weren't very random.

Comment: LCGs are far from perfect (the real flaws start showing when you consider vectors of numbers though, technically d-tuples show a regular lattice structure when plotted in d-dimensions), and indeed the lower bits are not that random (very small period) but the result of a modulo 3 operation is AFAIK not local on the lower bits (as opposed to e.g. modulo 2). 33% seems way too high. I wish I has a box with gcc on now, as I'm curious :) Unfortunately I'm on hols...

Comment: @Dr. G: clearly you're much more on top of this than I. Half of that comment wasn't in my vocabulary! (d-tuples?  d-dimensions? lattice structures?)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    srand(NULL);       
    cout << rand() % 10 + 1;
}
```

After running it 10 times, I got 1 every time. But I changed the seed to like this:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
//new include:
#include<time.h>
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));       
    cout << rand() % 10 + 1;
}
```

It is because the RANDOMIZER takes the seed(srand()), which happens to be null in the first one, then runs a given algorithm, which gives the output 1. If base the seed on time, thus making a "random" result.
Hope this helps.